# JAVA перериосвать JtextPane после JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

Есть JTextPane , Jcombobox
Когда человек заполняет форму, он может выбрать одно из значений JComboBox, хочу сделать так, чтобы при выборе определённого значения, JtextPane перерисовывался и текст становился как выбранное значение Jcombobox. Добавил listener и пытаюсь перерисовать весь JPanel но ничего не происходит при выборе значения в combobox, что не так делаю?

```
String[] taraChose = {
                "уп.",
                "мешок(ов)",
                "ящик(ов)",
                "бутылка(ок)"
                
            };
            final JComboBox taraType = new JComboBox(taraChose);
        
            newChem.add(taraType);
            
        
        final JTextPane dimP = new JTextPane();
        dimP.setText("В 1 " +taraType.getSelectedItem());
        dimP.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        dimP.setEditable(false);
        dimP.setBounds((int)(w*0.01), (int)(h*0.2), (int)(w*0.15), 25);
        newChem.add(dimP);
        
        taraType.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
             @Override
             public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                 System.out.println("itemchanged: "+ taraType.getSelectedItem());
           
                // storage.getContentPane().revalidate();
                 storage.getContentPane().repaint();
                 
             }
         });
```

Comment: Ну в листнер добавить строчку ту же dimP.setText("В 1 " +taraType.getSelectedItem());

Comment: @Perfect Voyage точно же) спасибо